# How to find matches on 128ticks server?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Hello :) I recently bought CS:GO and I've experienced a lot of "nohit issues".
After playing some games on 128 ticks community servers, i realized the game was way more enjoyable on these servers.

I was wondering how can I find a "competitive" match on these kind of servers (IRC chans, websites, private tournaments, ...) ?

What I would like to find in an optimal world would be a competitive matchmaking system, as it is implemented right now in CS:GO, but using "better" servers.

Have a nice day !

Comment: Try searching 128 or 128tick in the server browser, most of them should have it as a tag. If they dont.. well.. they're dumb :)

Comment: I may have formulated badly my question : I would like to find a "competitive" system, outside of the CS:GO one... Because I really enjoy the whole match "strategy" behind and I would like to be able to play "competitive matches" with friends, on real servers ;)

I'll edit my question :)

Comment: Try taking a gander around here http://www.csgoforum.com/Forum-cs-go-clans-and-recruiting

Comment: @johnkork What you ask for cannot be done. You can just join such a server with your friends and play as long as you wish and then leave. There is no support for competitive match making outside of the official competitive match making.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options you can look into:

- ESEA (http://play.esea.net/) - Requires paid subscription
- ALTPug (http://www.altpug.com/) - Free
- FaceIT (http://play.faceit.com/ - Free

I personally subscribe to ESEA and enjoy it thoroughly. The quality of server is much better than traditional matchmaking and skillful aiming is rewarded without having to worry about horrible registry.

Comment: These are all good, but be careful. If you are in low ranks, you will simply get obliterated in ESEA. Advice: Play, get good, then sub. (Speaking from personal experience. I subbed up before the ESEA Bitcoin miner malware fiasco. I was Eagle Master rank in Competitive, and I had absolutely NO chance in ESEA. I met pro players there, that was kind of fun, but I could not do anything. I simply had no chance against the enemy. The skill gap is HUGE between ESEA and even higher level Competitive.)

Answer (score -2):

To go on 128-tick server:

1. Go to steam -> games.
2. Right click on CSGO.
3. Select properties.
4. In the new window, click the "set launch options" button.
5. Another window will pop up. On the line type "-tickrate 128" (without the quotation marks but with the dash)

You will have to relaunch CSGO. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, but no. This would simply launch a 128 tickrate server IF you were to start a dedicated server.